# Understanding Erlang ODBC application

Tags: error-handling, erlang, odbc

I'm connecting to an DB source with Erlang ODBC. My code looks like:

```
main() ->
  Sql = "SELECT 1",
  Connection = connect(),
  case odbc:sql_query(Connection, Sql) of 
    {selected, Columns, Results} ->
      io:format("Success!~n Columns: ~p~n Results: ~p~n",
        [Columns, Results]),
      ok;
    {error, Reason} ->
      {error, Reason}
  end.

connect() ->
  ConnectionString = "DSN=dsn_name;UID=uid;PWD=pqd",
  odbc:start(),
  {ok, Conn} = odbc:connect(ConnectionString, []),
  Conn.
```

It's ok now. But how can I handle errors at least in my query? As I understand it contains in `{error, Reason}`, but how can I output it when something gone wrong? I'm trying to add io:format like at the first clause, but it doesn't work.

At second, unfortunately, I can't find any reference that can explain syntax well, I can't understand what does `ok` mean in this code (first - line 8, and second - line 16. If I'm right it just means the case that connection is ok and this variable isn't assigned? But what it means at 8 line?)

Answer (score 2):

`ok` in line 8 is the return value of the case statement when the call to `odbc:sql_query(Connection, Sql)` returns a result that can match the expression `{selected, Columns, Results}`. In this case it is useless since the function `io:format(...)` already returns `ok`.

the second ok: `{ok, Conn}` is a very common Erlang usage: the function returns a tuple `{ok,Value}` in case of success and `{error,Reason}` in case of failure. So you can match on the success case and extract the returned value with this single line:  `{ok, Conn} = odbc:connect(ConnectionString, []),`

In this case the function `connect()` doesn't handle the error case, so this code has 4 different possible behaviors:

- It can fails to connect to the database: the process will crash with a badmatch error at line 16.
- It connects to the database but the query fails: the main function will return the value `{error,Reason}`.
- It connects to the database and the query returns an answer that doesn't match the tuple `{selected, Columns, Results}`: the process will crash with a badmatch error at line 4.
- It connects to the database and the query returns an answer that matches the tuple `{selected, Columns, Results}`: the function will print

`Success!
      Columns: Column
      Results: Result`

and returns `ok`

Comment: Thank for the explanation, I feel much clearer now. But as you assumed: _It connects to the database but the query fails: the main function will return the value {error,Reason}._ .When *query* fails I'm getting nothing( But I would like to get some error like `column col_name not found`

Answer (score 1):

So I found something. The {error, Reason} contains the connection errors, means that we specified wrong DSN name etc. Regarding to my offer to catch query error we can read this from Erlang reference:

> **Gaurds** All API-functions are guarded and if you pass an argument of
>   the wrong type a runtime error will occur. All input parameters to
>   internal functions are trusted to be correct. It is a good programming
>   practise to only distrust input from truly external sources. You are
>   not supposed to catch these errors, it will only make the code very
>   messy and much more complex, which introduces more bugs and in the
>   worst case also covers up the actual faults. Put your effort on
>   testing instead, you should trust your own input.

Means that we should be careful about what we write. That's not bad.